# How to add a row on top of existing rows just below the header row using google-spreadsheet npm package?

Tags: node.js, npm, google-sheets-api

I'm able to add rows below the existing rows using the [google-spreadsheet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet) package.
However, I want to add the row on top of existing rows just below the header, i.e., at Row 2 and move the rest of the rows down.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately there is no way of inserting a row/column via the API without specifying a custom batch request body using the `google-spreadsheet` npm package, as it only supports bulk updates for cells and not for other batch requests.*

#### Workaround:

You can make a batch request to the API using the `spreadsheets.batchUpdate` method of the `googleapis` library and include an `InsertDimensionRequest` in the resource body.*

#### Code:

Firstly you need to build your request:

```js
var req = {
  spreadsheetId: "<spreadsheet-id>",
  resource: {
    request: [
      {
        spreadsheetId: "<spreadsheet-id>",
        resource: {
          requests: [
            insertDimension: {
              range: {
                sheetId: 0,
                dimension: "ROWS",
                startIndex: 1,
                endIndex: 2
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and then send it as the batchUpdate resource body:

```js
function makeRequest() {
  var sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth });

  sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({req, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
  });
}
```

#### References:

- [Google Sheets batchUpdate method](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)
- [InsertDimensionRequest update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#InsertDimensionRequest)
- [DimensionRange documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/DimensionRange)

Comment: I think you meant for the google-sheet-api. I'm using google-spreadsheet npm package, not the api directly.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry. Unfortunately there is no way of inserting a row/column via the API without specifying a custom batch request body - the `google-spreadsheet` npm package only supports bulk updates for cells not for rows.